# What's the difference between Windows 8.1 and Windows 8.1 N?

Tags: msdn, windows-8.1

I see both options available with different sizes in the MSDN Subscriptions Download but I can't tell the difference between the two versions besides the name and the size

Windows 8.1 N (multiple editions) (x64) - DVD (English) 3537 MB

Windows 8.1 (multiple editions) (x64) - DVD (English) 3719 MB

Comment: N lacks stuff like windows media player for the european market, since they banned bundling it. Practically there should be no difference.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek why did you answer in a comment?

Comment: its esssentially a duplicate of the question above, since its the same things that have been removed IMO